# Apple notarization and 10.14.5

Tags: macos, developer-program, notarization

We distribute an app for Mac OS outside of the Mac App store.  We have an apple account that we have used to generated signing certificates.  We heard about the new notarization requirements.  We have tested on 10.14.5 and we see no difference.

Where does Apple document this so we can understand if or how our account is grandfathered for builds in the field?

Comment: Welcome to the site - we have a strong policy of one question per question so I’ve combined both yours into a “where is this documented”. Once you have an answer there or if you don’t get an answer - feel free to edit the post above to have the more important of the two questions asked directly. you can then ask a second question (or a follow on question - linking here as needed for context)

Answer (score 1):

Apple documents the requirements here:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_your_app_before_distribution

The section that governs is yellow and hilighted:

> ## Important
>
> Beginning in macOS 10.14.5, all new or updated kernel extensions and all software from developers new to distributing with Developer ID must be notarized in order to run. Beginning in macOS 10.15, notarization is required by default for all software.

So, your whole account isn’t new so unless you make a new developer account, you are not required to notarize anything that’s current or in the field as long you don’t have a kernel extension.

Those are mandatory today for all updates and new builds. Your tests are what I expect and you surely can notarize everything now so you are set for 10.15

The developer I read closely for all the underpinnings and reverse engineering of this process is Howard Oakley and his Eclectic Light blog - it’s amazingly well written, clear and technically deep about how gatekeeper works in practice and what things Apple has and has not documented yet.

- https://eclecticlight.co/tag/notarization/